# A good static file server as a service

Tags: django

I'm looking for an easy to use static file service that I can use with my application server. I'm using Django and just need a simple service that let's me host static files that I can call from my templates.

It would be best if the service had an easy way to secure certain files and had a way to easily integrate that secure file sending.

I could just use a webserver I have, but I'm currently testing Heroku and it doesn't host static files. I'd use my other webservers, but I'm looking for something that can handle the secure files better then just an ngix server. I'm not a great admin so I was hoping for a easy-to-use API based or something static server host.

Essentially I want to do what is described in here: http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=1929

But from a server that is not "local" to the application server, like http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile that requires.

Comment: why don't you use your web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that depends on what you need.  Are you looking for a CDN, then go to google and search CDN and spend a few hours picking one out.  If you're looking to store user uploaded files perhaps try S3.

If your looking for how to deal with this in django. Well then that's what the STATIC_URL (or MEDIA_URL) setting handles for you (as well as the {{ MEDIA_URL }} idiom is for in templates (replaced by [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) in django 1.3)